# Cesium PinBuilder using "fromMakiIconId"

Tags: cesiumjs

I started using cesium for representing 3d maps and was trying to add Point of Interest data on top of this 3d view. I tried local png icons and it worked. I also realized can add icons from built in assets. I tried the below code and it worked perfect. I have a various set of PoIs but could not find the labels using which I can add them onto the map.

[image: Image from PinBuilder documentation]

For example to add a hospital i referred hospital in the iconid.

```
var hospitalPin = Cesium.when(
  pinBuilder.fromMakiIconId("hospital", Cesium.Color.RED, 48),
  function (canvas) {
    return viewer.entities.add({
      name: "Hospital",
      position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(77.311, 32.826),
      billboard: {
        image: canvas.toDataURL(),
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
      },
    });
  }
);
```

In the similar way is there any reference for the icon Ids which I can use to make use of them in my code to represent the PoIs. Any help is appreciated.

I found the source images located at \Build\Cesium\Assets\Textures\maki from the cesium library which I think can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The image you posted is from the [PinBuilder docs](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PinBuilder.html), but check out the original source for that:  It's a screenshot of the [Cesium Sandcastle GeoJson Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=GeoJSON%20simplestyle.html).

As you noticed, the images of the individual pins are stored in [a folder called maki](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/tree/master/Source/Assets/Textures/maki) which has names like this:

```
airport.png
alcohol-shop.png
america-football.png
art-gallery.png
bakery.png
bank.png
bar.png
baseball.png
...
```

Just strip the `.png` off the end of the image filename, and that's it.  That's the ID.

The dashes are allowed in the ID:

```
pinBuilder.fromMakiIconId("america-football", Cesium.Color.RED, 48)
```

But, the first few pins in the original screenshot don't have corresponding Maki icons, they're simple letters or numbers.  You can build pins using text, using a different function, like this:

```
pinBuilder.fromText("A", Cesium.Color.RED, 48)
```

You may also use pins with [Unicode characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/So) on them.

```
pinBuilder.fromText("\u267b", Cesium.Color.RED, 48)
```

And finally, if you have a custom PNG file of your own, similar to a Maki icon but customized for your app's need, you may build a pin directly from the URL of the custom PNG file.

```
pinBuilder.fromUrl(url, Cesium.Color.RED, 48)
```